# Using post array data to create multiple forms that have to be actioned singularly

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I am making a training course signoff page.

I am submitting a list of users and documents that have attended and been trained. Now i wish to make a signoff page for each user (from post data) that attended.

I would like to create a form that shows the user and requests their password to continue. (this will submit a mysql query into the db), if there are more users in the post data then to produce a form for the next person to sign, and so on until all users in the post data array have completed. Then return to a standard page once all have completed. (or skipped). I would like the ability to skip a user and move to the next if they decide not to sign.

I have tried a number of loops, and foreach and used hidden inputs to see if i can cycle through users, however after the first one i always seem to come unstuck.

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?><div class="card-box">
 <?php
 $posttrainer=$_POST['trainer'];
 $postlocation=$_POST['location'];
 $postdatetrained=$_POST['datetrained'];
 $postaddnotes=$_POST['additionalnotes'];
 $posttdocs=$_POST['tdocs'];
 $posttusers=$_POST['tusers'];
 $totaldocs=sizeof($posttdocs); // do not worry about this for now
 $totalusers=sizeof($posttusers); // key factor

for($i=0;$i<$totalusers;$i++){
$TUSERS=$posttusers[$i];
print"<input value=".$TUSERS." name='user[]'><BR>";


?><form method="post" name="submit" id="" action="gotonextuser.php"> 

<label>User Name:                                       
<input class="form-control" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo $TUSERS; ?>" id="trainer" required="true" readonly></label> 

<label>Location of Training:                                     
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="?php echo $postlocation; ?>" id="location" name="location" required="true"></label> 

<label>Disclaimer:
<textarea readonly> Lots of disclaimer text in here</textarea>
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" value="" id="location" name="disclaimer" required="true"></label>       </form>                     
<?php } ?>  </div>                                                  
<?php    
}
```

In the above example i have posted from a previous sheet:
4 users as an array. The code above, is looping through each of those (as expected, but all on one page. I want to deal with 1 user, then press submit then see the inputs for the next user, if I press submit i'll insert a sql query to the db and move to user 2, if i press skip ill move to user 2 (without an insert to mysql_db), and so on.

Comment: Please share all your relevant code with us. Not enough information to give you an answer.

Comment: Have added more, hope this helps give clarity @EternalHour Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use $_SESSIONS, i will demonstrate:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['tusers']=array();
array_push( $_SESSION['tusers'] , 'user1');
array_push( $_SESSION['tusers'] , 'user2');
array_push( $_SESSION['tusers'] , 'user3');

var_dump($_SESSION);


array_pop($_SESSION['tusers']);
var_dump($_SESSION);

array_pop($_SESSION['tusers']);
var_dump($_SESSION);

?>
```

now what you can do is to put this code in tow different files, for example you can populate the  $_SESSION['tusers'] with the $_POST['tusers'] in build_users_array.php

### so in build_users_array.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['tusers']=array();
array_push( $_SESSION['tusers'] , 'user1');
array_push( $_SESSION['tusers'] , 'user2');
array_push( $_SESSION['tusers'] , 'user3');
```

and when you click on a user you can activate the pop_from_users_array.php

### pop_from_users_array.php:

```html
$current_pop_user = array_pop($_SESSION['tusers']);
echo $x;
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**as you can see $current_pop_user is : user3, and the $_SESSION['tusers'] now only holds the user1 and user2 values**

Comment: I got this to work, however have decided on a different approach and used Modals with a list of all users that must open a modal and sign off to say agreed to the training which passes back a value into a hidden input. So thank you @Klienblat for the support it has given me some substance into this field of view.